How to remove specific parts of text from string?
I am using Python. I have a dataframe with string "description". In these strings, I have things like: "п. 5.6.2 ГОСТ 2.114-2016", "п. 4.1 ГОСТ 2.102-2013", "п.5 ГОСТ Р 51672-2000" and so on. I want to remove them.
I tried this code:
import pandas as pd
import re

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'description': ["п. 5.6.2 ГОСТ 2.114-2016",
                        "п. 4.1 ГОСТ 2.102-2013",
                        "п.5 ГОСТ Р 51672-2000"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the regex pattern to match the specified format
pattern = r'п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ(?:\s*Р)?\s*\d+(?:-\d+)*'

# Remove the matched patterns from the 'description' column
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(pattern, '', x))

print(df)

but result is:
              description
0               .114-2016
1               .102-2013
2                     

What  am I doing wrong?

You did not account for digits + ., try using п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ(?:\s*Р)?(?:\s*\d+\.)?\s*\d+(?:-\d+)* instead.

pattern = r'п..+ГОСТ.+-\d{2,4}' and pandas.Series.str.replace.

use this п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ.* you dont need to make it super accurate, the start is fine

The point is that your regex matches numbers that do not support dots inside them, see the \d+ in \d+(?:-\d+)*.
So, you can use \d*\.?\d+ or \d+(?:\.\d+)* instead of \d+:
п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ(?:\s*Р)?\s*\d*\.?\d+(?:-\d*\.?\d+)*
п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ(?:\s*Р)?\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*

See regex demo #1 and regex demo #2.
I'd use п\.\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*ГОСТ(?:\s*Р)?\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*, as the standardization codes cannot start with a . char, and \d*\.?\d+ allows them, but both should work in your data set.
Cf:

\d*\.?\d+ - zero or more digits, then an optional dot, and then one or more digits
\d+(?:\.\d+)* - one or more digits, and then zero or more repetitions of . and one or more digits.

